# Django Pyinstaller .EXE gives me ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.urls'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, anaconda, pyinstaller

I am trying to run a Django project using an EXE file compiled using Pyinstaller. But when I run the compiled .EXE file using this command I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.urls'` and another `OsError: [WinError 123]`. I will explain how I setup this stuff later.

Here is the full error when I run the .EXE file:

```
C:\Users\omen\Desktop\dist\dj>dj.exe runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 865, in run
  File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
  File "C:\Users\omen\Desktop\dist\dj\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in check
  File "site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
  File "site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
  File "site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
  File "site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
  File "site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
  File "site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 584, in url_patterns
  File "site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
  File "site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\omen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "dj\dj\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.urls'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dj\manage.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "dj\manage.py", line 20, in main
  File "site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
  File "site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
  File "site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
  File "C:\Users\omen\Desktop\dist\dj\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
  File "C:\Users\omen\Desktop\dist\dj\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\omen\Desktop\dist\dj\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 598, in run_with_reloader
  File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 583, in start_django
  File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 301, in run
  File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 307, in run_loop
  File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 347, in tick
  File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 363, in snapshot_files
  File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 262, in watched_files
  File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
  File "site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 139, in iter_modules_and_files
  File "pathlib.py", line 1339, in exists
  File "pathlib.py", line 1161, in stat
OSError: [WinError 123] La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
[11168] Failed to execute script manage
```

First I installed `Pyinstaller` and other dependencies using the commands:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller
conda install django
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
conda install -c anaconda psycopg2
```

Then I installed `OSGeo4W64` on my Windows 10 machine for `GDAL`.

I added this in `settings.py`:

```
import os


if os.name == 'nt':
    import platform
    OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W"
    if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
        OSGEO4W += "64"
    assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
    os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\gdal"
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
    os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'dj.settings'

SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates'),
)

GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\geos_c.dll'
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal204.dll'
```

I also generated a spec file using this command:

```
pyi-makespec dj/manage.py
```

And this is the generated `manage.spec`:
(I added in `datas` the templates folder but it didn't work...)

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['dj\\manage.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\omen\\Desktop'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('app/templates','app/templates')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='manage',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='manage')
```

Then I generated the project using this command:

```
pyinstaller --name=dj dj/manage.py
```

Also I edited libgdal.py to have the following:

```
# Custom library path set?
try:
    from django.conf import settings
    lib_path = settings.GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH
except (AttributeError, ImportError, ImproperlyConfigured, OSError):
    lib_path = None
```

Here is my main urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls')),
]
```

And here is INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app'
]
```

Please help!!!

Comment: what is your main `urls.py`

Comment: @Moha369 I added it in the end

Comment: and what is your `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: @Moha369 check question

Comment: 1- is the app you created called `app`2- is there a `urls.py` in the app ?

Comment: @Moha369 YES & OF COURSE YES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I able to fix this problem...

Here is what I have done:

1. Generate spec file using `pyi-makespec dj/manage.py`
2. Add app.urls in hiddenimports such as `hiddenimports=['app.urls',],`
3. Use this command instead `pyinstaller manage.spec`

Finally!!!

Answer (score 0):

This might not solve for Django, but it solved my issues with Plotly maps. I put this code into my .spec file and was able to run Plotly charts after going through PyInstaller. Could not get my maps to show and was getting error messages.

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>"
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.validators.choropleth' pyinstaller
```

Now it works using the below:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['napdgui.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\Python\\NAPD\\napdguiv1'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\plotly\\', 'plotly'),
                ],
             hiddenimports=['pkg_resources.py2_warn', 'app.urls'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='Tool v08122020',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='Analysis Tool v081320')
```